# Flash complaining about instance names?

Tags: flash

I have a Flash CS4 FLA throwing the following error when I hit Ctrl+Enter to test the movie:

```
WARNING: Multiple 3D objects on the same frame have the same instance name. 3D instance names must be unique. All but one of the instances will be renamed during export.
```

On my layers, I can't see any duplicate instance names, and Flash doesn't give me ANY indication as to which names are causing the problem.

I know it's to do with two layers making use of 3D Tween. When I hide them, the problem goes. I've even tried removing and replacing the Symbols.

First of all, I have to have the objects on those layers Tween in 3D, and I have to give them instance names as I refer to them from ActionScript code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens for me when I have accidentally copied and pasted-in-place a copy of an object over the top of itself.

If you know what movieclip is causing the problem, then find it and delete it to see if there is another copy underneath. If not, then you will have to go through manually deleting and undoing till you find it.

Comment: It would have been useful if Flash had a layer view for each, um...well...layer, if that makes sense. Coz you can copy objects on top of objects and not even know they are there.

Comment: if they have instance names, then you can view them using the movie explorer panel. But that panel does not work well at all :(

Answer (score 0):

I've found there's a bug that doesn't allow you to mask multiple instances of the same 3D object with the same mask. You need to mask each instance separately.